# JQuery project with excel like feature?

Tags: jquery

I have two projects both somewhat similar, One needs to have excel like features.

One is basically a `table` with products to `select` and price of the product, the amount of products you would like(5, 10 whatever number). and the total price of the product. multiple rows like that. And to calculate the tax at the end.

The code below is also in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blade1989/w7r3gp8e/). The codes I found by Google-ing around. its somewhat incomplete, because I kept stumbling on my lack of knowledge of JQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>JSfiddle</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
tr, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

table {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
}

.btw, .aantal {
    text-align: center;
}

.aantal input {
    width: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

.totaal {
    text-align: center;
}

td {
    max-width: 450px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:nth-child(odd)").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
    $("tr:nth-child(even)").css("background-color", "#F9F9F9");  
});

      $(function(){
        $('input[name=aantal]').change(function(){
            $('#select').text($(this).val());
        });
        $('#element_1').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function(){
            $('#advertiserNameDisplay').html($(this).val());
        });
        $('#element_2').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function(){
            $('#adImageDisplay').text($(this).val());
        });
        $('#element_3').bind('keydown keyup keypress', calcPrice);
        function calcPrice(){
            var months = parseInt($('#element_3').val());
            if (!isNaN(months)){
                var rate = 1;
                if (months >= 1 && months < 3){
                    rate = 199;
                }else if (months >= 3 && months < 6){
                    rate = 175;
                }else{
                    rate = 150;
                }   
                var price = rate * months;
                $('#rate').text(rate);
                $('#months').text(months);
                $('#total').text(price);
            }else{
                $('#months').text('-');
            }
        }
        calcPrice();
      });

</script>

</head>
<body>


  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>article</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>tax</th>
    <th>price €</th>
    <th>amount</th>
    <th>total price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">

        <select name="products">
          <option value="One">Product One</option>
          <option value="Two">Product Two</option>
          <option value="Three">Product Three</option>
          <option value="Four">Product Four</option>
          <option value="Five">Product Five</option>
        </select>

    </td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" min="1" max="5" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="article">XXXXX</td>
    <td class="Description">A Product</td>
    <td class="tax">6</td>
    <td class="price">€ 4.0</td>
    <td class="amount"><input name="amount" value="" type="number"></td>
    <td class="total">€ 0.00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>amount</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Different delivery address:</td>
    <td>A adres</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Subtotal</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <b>128 packages per pallet</b>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>extra cost*:</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="border: 0px none; ">
    <td style="border: 0px none;">payment Bank</td>
    <td>payment  10%</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>tax 6%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="border: 0px none; ">
    <td style="border: 0px none;"></td>
    <td>AFTER PAYMENT  90%</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>total</td>
    <td><span id="select">x</span></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="border: 0px none; ">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>payment 10%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>extra cost</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>AFTER PAYMENT 90%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>comments</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>


</tbody></table>








</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it like an xls file, with `sum`. But, I have no idea how to do that. My JQuery isn't that great when it comes to doing calculations.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://handsontable.com/examples.html#fndtn-basic

Comment: @RobertRozas that to advanced. The least i wanna know, is how do I multipley inputs. What works now, is the value of the `number` input is put in the `<span id="select">x</span>`, but, if I press another input number, then the span just shows that value! It does not multiply!? Any idea how? that js code is in the answer and fiddle!

Comment: It's a shame you're not using a front end framework. I think you'll have great difficulty doing this in one table as well..

Comment: @Invent-Animate Any help would be appreciated! And for future reference, what Front End Framework would you suggest!